# A little abbreviated response

Tags: riddle, wordplay

This is a short riddle which has a short answer.

I look like I have no memory,
but I am fine,
but turn me around
and I may knock you down.

Comment: Cute, simple, and fun! I loved this one c:

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think the answer is

> OK

I look like I have no memory

> OK looks like 0K (zero kilobytes)

but I am fine,

> OK is synonymous with fine.

but turn me around and I may knock you down.

> OK backwards is KO (an acronym for knock out)