# Common Marsupials and Rare Antelopes

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, language, animals

Following the surge of riddles from senpais: [this by jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85123/im-yearning-in-grey), and [this by Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85125/i-wish-i-yearn-for-an-answer-to-this-riddle)

> I hide as a puzzle in Malaysian spoon,
>   Bounding sturdy monument and sturdy wood.
>   Upside-down in common marsupials' and rare antelopes' front,
>   I'm a gesture, or three, for good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope my initial thoughts for your puzzle are

> OK

I hide as a puzzle in Malaysian spoon,

> sud**ok**u  is a puzzle which contains ok hiding in sudu - spoon in Malaysian.

Bounding sturdy monument and sturdy wood.

> **o**a**k** and **o**belis**k** for the sturdy wood and stone column.

Upside-down in common marsupials' and rare antelopes' front,

> **ko**ala and **ko**ngoni (aka the hartebeest) have ok reversed on their front.

I'm a gesture, or three, for good.

> **[OK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OK)** - just OK, Okay or Okey dokey, and as a coincidence [my first puzzle!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28312/a-little-abbreviated-response)

Comment: Also it is made by $$\color{blue}{\text{OK}}$$ Tom got a hat-trick 

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Self promotion much? :-)

Comment: nailed it! will award check later :)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Hmmm...

Comment: @Tom better words are expected for line one and line three latter part (should also be in reverse)

Comment: Thank you @OmegaKrypton - that was extra nice cluing for the first line!

Answer (score 3):

**Very partial answer**

*I hide as a puzzle in Malaysian spoon,*

> The internet code for Malaysia is `.my`, so this could mean **my spoon**. Interpreting "spoon" as Spoonerism, we might want to rearrange some letters: instead of "a puzzle in my", maybe **a muzzle in pie**? (Or "spy moon", but then the word "spoon" would be playing double roles.)

*Bounding sturdy monument and sturdy wood.*

> I want to interpret "bounding" as being on the boundary rather than running. Probably there's some crossword-style letterplay going on here, and we're looking for first and last letters or some such.

*Standing upside-down in marsupials' and antelopes' front,*

> This *definitely* looks like letterplay. The best-known marsupial must be the kangaroo, but turning "k" upside down gives nothing meaningful. The second best-known is probably the **possum**, and turning "p" upside down gives **d**. That d could be an upside-down p from the front of both "possum" (marsupial) and "pronghorn" (antelope).

*I'm a gesture, or three, for good.*

> If we're still looking for letters, that could be **V**, as the V sign has [three meanings listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_sign).